# TensorFlow graph building slow with branched networks (e.g. ResNeXt)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to implement a ResNeXt block (type B) from the paper in TensorFlow:

[image: ResNext Block B]

To do so, I've used a loop to generate each path depending on the cardinality parameter (`cardinality = 32` in the image above)

```
def resnext_block(input_tensor, filters, stride=1, projection=False, cardinality=32, depth=4):
    residual = input_tensor

    # Split
    branches = []
    for i in range(cardinality):
        with tf.variable_scope("branch%i" % i):
            branch = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=input_tensor, filters=depth, kernel_size=1, padding='same')
            branch = tf.layers.batch_normalization(branch, training=train_flag)
            branch = activation(branch)
            branch = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=branch, filters=depth, kernel_size=3, strides=stride, padding='same')
            branch = tf.layers.batch_normalization(branch, training=train_flag)
            branch = activation(branch)
            branches.append(branch)

    # Merge
    merged = tf.concat(branches, -1)
    # Transform
    transformed = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=merged, filters=filters, kernel_size=1, padding='same')
    transformed = tf.layers.batch_normalization(transformed, training=train_flag)

    if projection:
        residual = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=input_tensor, filters=filters, kernel_size=1, strides=stride)
        residual = tf.layers.batch_normalization(residual, training=train_flag)

    return activation(transformed + residual)
```

If I run my model for low values of cardinality (< 4), the graph builds quickly and training gets underway.

For high values of cardinality, TensorFlow spends a very long time building the graph (i.e. with 1 CPU core at 100% and no other activity). The events file grows very large (> 1GB) presumably because there are so many nodes in the graph (despite the fact the number of trainable parameters can be kept to a similar number by reducing `depth`).

Are there any tricks I'm missing to speed up/optimise this process?

I'm not seeing very many ResNeXt examples in TensorFlow (the ones I have found have cardinality set to small numbers), which makes me think maybe the graph architecture in TF is not suited for these types of models.

## Update

It looks like grouped convolutions are the best way to achieve this (block style C in the paper). However these are not yet implemented in TF 1.10. See this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3332)